# Detecting active tab in Chrome background script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

I want to detect in a Chrome extension background script what is the active browser tab with focus if any.

I have the code below that works in almost all cases. However, if I restore a minimized app (eg. Outlook) that hides the browser window then the `onFocusChange` event doesn't fire.

```
chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener((windowId) => {
    console.log('On focus change: ' + windowId);
    handleActiveTab();
});

chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener((e) => {
    console.log('On activated', e);
    handleActiveTab();
});
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((e) => {
    console.log('On updated', e);
    handleActiveTab();
});

const handleActiveTab = () => {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true, lastFocusedWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
        if (tabs[0]) {
            chrome.windows.get(tabs[0].windowId, (w) => {
                if (w && w.focused) {
                    console.log('ACTIVE TAB -> ' + tabs[0].url);
                } else {
                    console.log('ACTIVE TAB WITHOUT FOCUS -> ' + tabs[0].url);
                }
            });
        } else {
            console.log('NO ACTIVE TAB');
        }
    });
};
```

If I call my `handleActiveTab` with a timer then it detects, that the browser tab lost the focus. The `window.focused` property changes. But why the `onFocusChanged` event is not fired?

As a workaround, I can use the solution with a timer, but I would like to avoid it if possible.

Comment: It's a bug in Chrome, https://crbug.com/516740, https://crbug.com/387377.

Comment: Thanks, good to know. It is almost an 8-year-old bug, hmmm ....

Comment: The actual bug is probably even older, I just found the more recent reports.